# ScalaTest PlayFramework

Tags: scala, playframework, tdd, playframework-2.4

Trying to do some TDD while learning the playframework:

```
class ContentFetching extends PlaySpec with BeforeAndAfter with MockFactory
{
  private val service = ContentService

  private val languages = List(Language(Some(1), "en", "English", "Placeholder"),
                               Language(Some(2), "de", "Deutsch", "Platzhalter")
                              )

  "find" must
  {
    "fail if languageCode is invalid" in
    {
      val fakeRepository = mock[LanguageRepositoryTrait]
      (fakeRepository.get _).expects().returning(languages)

      fakeRepository.get must have length 3

      service.find("fr") must be Result.NotFound

    }
  }
}
```

ContentService would call:

```
def fourOhFour() = NotFound(s"Oops, content could not be found")
```

yet the assertion `service.find("fr") must be Result.NotFound` won't compile. Why is that and how to test this then?
Here is the whole contentService (as requested) Sadly it extends Controller currently, because I found no other way to return an Action. Actually I use MVC, but a Service + repository-layer as well:

```
class ContentServiceComponent(languageRepository: LanguageRepositoryTrait, nodeRepository: NodeRepositoryTrait) extends Controller
{
  def find(language: String) = Action
  {
    languageRepository.get().map(l => l.code).contains(language) match
    {
      case true => Ok(s"Homepage for $language")
      case false => fourOhFour()
    }
  }

  def fourOhFour() = NotFound(s"Oops, content could not be found")
}

object ContentService extends ContentServiceComponent(LanguageRepository, NodeRepository)
```

Comment: Is ContentServices a controller? Could you post that clase too or at least find method

Comment: It is, although I would prefer it not to be, as it's another layer I added for decoupling. I added the class

Comment: what's the error the compiler prints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

service.find("fr") from the Play controller returns a Result

Maybe you're comparing a Result with Result.Status type?

Can you use a `play.api.helper`?

```
status(of: Future[Result]) = Await.result(of, timeout.duration).header.status
```

Instead of

```
service.find("fr") must be Result.NotFound
```

Try something like this?

```
status(service.find("fr")) must be NOT_FOUND
```

`NOT_FOUND` is a `play.api.http.Status` value and just maps to the standard HTTP status code 404

Answer (score 0):

`find` instead returns `Action` could return `Option`

```
def find(language: String): Option[String] =
  {
    languageRepository.get().map(l => l.code).contains(language) match
    {
      case true => Some(s"Homepage for $language")
      case _ => None
    }
  }
```

So you cound handle it at Controller as follow:

```
def index(language:String) = Action{

ContentService.find(language) match{
  case Some(content) => Ok(content)
  case _ => NotFound(s"Oops, content could not be found")
}
```

}

and you could do test case something like this:

```
class ContentFetching extends PlaySpec with BeforeAndAfter with MockFactory
{


  val languages = List(Language(Some(1), "en", "English",Placeholder"),Language(Some(2), "de", "Deutsch", "Platzhalter")
                              )

val languagesRepositoryMockHere = new LanguageRepositoryTrait{ 
    override def get =  languages  //I don't  know the implementations
}

  "find" must
  {
    "fail if languageCode is invalid" in
    {
       private val service = new ContentServiceComponent(languagesRepositoryMockHere,nodeRepositoryMockHere)


      service.find("fr") shouldBe None

    }
  }
}
```

This was not tested but could help for reference.

Cheers.

Comment: Of course this works, but it's not what I wanted to achieve. Workarounds are fine, I nearly almost find one myself, but I am eager to learn why it does not work how I think it should be able to work.